# How can i write an equivalent sql query for pivot with complex aggregations in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark, pivot, aggregates

In spark we can provide complex aggregates with pivot.
e.g.

```
project.groupBy("mgr","job").pivot("job").agg(sum(project.col("salary")).alias("ss") * count("*").alias("c"))
```

On below data i.e. project

| mgr | deptno | salary | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | 10 | 100 | CLERK |
| APAC | 20 | 200 | MANAGER |
| APAC | 20 | 300 | CLERK |
| APAC | 10 | 400 | CLERK |
| JPAC | 20 | 1000 | CLERK |
| JPAC | 10 | 2000 | MANAGER |
| EMEA | 20 | 10000 | CLERK |
| EMEA | 20 | 40000 | MANAGER |
| EMEA | 20 | 30000 | CLERK |

Output :

| mgr | job | CLERK | MANAGER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMEA | MANAGER | null | 40000 |
| JPAC | MANAGER | null | 2000 |
| EMEA | CLERK | 80000 | null |
| JPAC | CLERK | 1000 | null |
| APAC | CLERK | 2400 | null |
| APAC | MANAGER | null | 200 |

Can I write a similar sql query using pivot in oracle database?

Comment: Output summary of salary doesn't match the input table. for EMEA salary of CLERK will be 40000(10000+30000) instead of 80000.

Comment: It is Sum * Count right. So 40000 * 2.

Comment: Ok got it. Now changing my query

Answer (score 1):

Here goes two version of what you need (Hope both will help you):

**Query#1**

```
select * from (
select mgr,job,salary from project
)
pivot
(
    sum(salary)
    for job in ('CLERK','MANAGER')
)
```

**Output#1**

```
MGR     JOB      'CLERK'    'MANAGER'
JPAC    CLERK    1000    - 
JPAC    MANAGER   -          2000
APAC    CLERK    800         - 
APAC    MANAGER   -          200
EMEA    CLERK    40000   - 
EMEA    MANAGER   -          40000
```

**Query#2:**

```
select * from (
select mgr,job,salary from project
)
pivot
(
    sum(salary)
    for Job  in ('CLERK','MANAGER')
)
```

**Output#2:**

```
MGR    'CLERK'  'MANAGER'
EMEA    40000    40000
APAC    800      200
JPAC    1000     2000
```

**Query#3 (SUM()*COUNT()):**

```
select * from (
select mgr,job,job JobToPivot,sum(salary)*count(*) salary from project
group by mgr,job
)
pivot
(
    max(salary)
    for JobToPivot  in ('CLERK','MANAGER')
)
```

**Output#3:**

```
MGR     JOB     'CLERK' 'MANAGER'
JPAC    CLERK    1000    - 
JPAC    MANAGER  -       2000
APAC    CLERK    2400    - 
APAC    MANAGER  -       200
EMEA    CLERK    80000   - 
EMEA    MANAGER  -       40000
```

**Query#4 (sum()*COUNT()):**

```
select * from (
select mgr,job,sum(salary)*count(*) salary from project
group by mgr,job
)
pivot
(
    max(salary)
    for Job  in ('CLERK','MANAGER')
)
```

**Output#4:**

```
MGR    'CLERK'  'MANAGER'
EMEA    80000   40000
APAC    2400    200
JPAC    1000    2000
```

Comment: In spark query provided aggregation is
sum(project.col("salary")).alias("ss") * count("*").alias("c"). So we would need sum and count both in sql query.

Comment: Please have a look now.

Comment: I think Query 4 needs some modifications, like an alias can be used with sum(salary) *count() and some functione like max can be passed as aggregate within pivot. So 
select * from (
select mgr,job,sum(salary)*count(*) as sum_count salary from project
group by mgr,job
)
pivot
(
    max(sum_count)
    for Job  in ('CLERK','MANAGER')
)
could be the right query.

Comment: Since the answer was right didn't notice in hurry. I have changed my answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your result set doesn't make sense to me.  Wouldn't one of these be more useful?

```
select mgr, job, sum(salary)
from project
group by mgr, job;
```

This creates a separate row for each `mgr` and `job`, but only one salary.

Or:

```
select mgr,
       sum(case when job = 'CLERK' then salary end) as clerk,
       sum(case when job = 'MANAGER' then salary end) as manager
from project
group by mgr;
```

This has one row per `mgr` with the salaries populated in both salary columns.

Both of these are standard SQL (unlike `pivot`) and should run in any database.

Comment: You are right. We can implement pivot with (aggregate+filters) without using pivot keyword. And that will work in any database. What i am trying to do is just like spark if we can provide complex aggregations  with pivot in a sql.